# Linear FEM: Infinitesima Strain tensor at different element mesh

Tags: finite-element-method, solid-mechanics

[image]

Hi guys, 
I am solving an exercise for a course of Computational Continuum Mechanics. Briefly, my question is how can i compute the infinitesimal strain tensor at different nodes of the finite element mesh ?  I try to explain: I solved an exercise and I have a perfectly working code in MATLAB ( I attach it at the end, you can copy and paste it and run it if you want.) which compute the displacement vector field in the simple case of a rotation of pi/4 of a rigid body making use of the FEM under the assumption of a liner constitutive behavior of the material.[image]

Now I am asked to do the following :
"Compute in the finite element program the infinitesimal strain tensor at several different nodes of the finite element mesh. Compare these values with those obtained analytically in the previous question."

Yet I don't quite catch what I am supposed to do. I know I can compute the strain with something like this ( with $e_{0}$ the orientation in the initial state) $ \begin{equation}\epsilon(\overrightarrow{e_{0}})=\overrightarrow{e_{0}} \cdot \boldsymbol{\epsilon} \cdot \overrightarrow{e_{0}}\end{equation}$. I also know that the infinitesimal strain is defined as $\begin{equation}\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}\left[\boldsymbol{F}+\boldsymbol{F}^{T}\right]-\boldsymbol{I}\end{equation}$ and I am indeed able to compute it afterwards.

- I know that the strain tensor should be a local property defined point by point but I cannot think of a way to formally evaluate it at a mesh node

Someone can help me out ?

---

```
% PARAMETERS
```

% geometric:
H = 10; % height, in mm
L = 10; % length, in mm
% prescribed rotation angle and rotation tensor
theta = pi/4;
% material properties, in MPa
G     = 1000;
kappa = 3000;

% define the basis
ee = cartesianbasis2d('e1', 'e2');
e1 = ee(1);
e2 = ee(2);

% determine material coefficient tensor
I   = identity(2, ee);
I4  = identity(4, ee);
I4S = 1/2 * (I4 + rtranspose(I4));
C   = kappa * I*I + 2*G * (I4S - 1/3*I*I);

% make FE mesh
m1 = 3; % number of elements in horizontal direction
m2 = 3; % number of elements in vertical direction
[x, conn] = femgrid([ L  H ], [ m1  m2 ], ee, 'ElementType', 'Linear');
m = size(conn, 1); % number of elements in the mesh
n = size(x, 1);    % number of nodes in the mesh

% coordinates of integration points 
% (in the coordinate system of the master element)
% and the weight factors
xi = [ -1/sqrt(3)*e1 - 1/sqrt(3)*e2
        1/sqrt(3)*e1 - 1/sqrt(3)*e2
        1/sqrt(3)*e1 + 1/sqrt(3)*e2
       -1/sqrt(3)*e1 + 1/sqrt(3)*e2 ];
w  = [ 1
       1
       1
       1 ];

% assemble system matrices in element loop
K = zeros(2, ee, n, n); % zero matrix of nxn 2nd order tensors in basis ee

for e = 1:m % loop over all elements

```
iie = conn(e, :); % nodes of the current element e
xe  = x(iie);     % coordinates of these nodes

% compute element matrices in integration point loop
Ke = zeros(2, ee, 4, 4); % zero matrix of 4x4 2nd order tensors in basis ee

for k_integration_point = 1:4 % loop over integration points 

    xi1 = dot(xi(k_integration_point), e1); % x1 coordinate of the current integr. point
    xi2 = dot(xi(k_integration_point), e2); % x2 coordinate of the current integr. point

   % column of the shape functions
    Ne = [ 1/4*(1-xi1)*(1-xi2)
           1/4*(1+xi1)*(1-xi2)
           1/4*(1+xi1)*(1+xi2)
           1/4*(1-xi1)*(1+xi2) ];

    % column of the gradient of the shape functions
    % with respect to the local coordinates of the mater element
    gradxiNe = [ -1/4*(1-xi2)*e1 - 1/4*(1-xi1)*e2
                  1/4*(1-xi2)*e1 - 1/4*(1+xi1)*e2
                  1/4*(1+xi2)*e1 + 1/4*(1+xi1)*e2
                 -1/4*(1+xi2)*e1 + 1/4*(1-xi1)*e2 ];
    % Jacobian
    J = gradxiNe' * xe; 
    % column of the gradient of the shape functions
    % with respect to the global coordinates of the mesh
    gradNe = dot(inv(J), gradxiNe); 

    % element matrix and right hand side  ??????????????????
                                        Ke = Ke + w(k_integration_point)*dot(gradNe,C,gradNe')*det(J);     

end % end of integration point loop
```

% assembly
    K(iie, iie) = K(iie, iie) + Ke;

end % end of element loop

% apply boundary conditions by partitioning:
bottom = [ 1:(m1+1) ]; % nodes on the bottom boundary of the mesh
left   = [ (m1+2):(m1+1):(m1+1)*(m2) ]; % nodes on the left boundary of the mesh
right  = [ 2*(m1+1):(m1+1):(m1+1)*(m2) ]; % nodes on the right boundary of the mesh
top    = [ ((m1+1)*m2+1):(m1+1)*(m2+1) ]; % nodes on the top boundary of the mesh
% nodes where essential b.c. are applied
iiu = [bottom left right top];
% the remaining nodes
iif = setdiff(1:n, iiu);

Kuu = K(iiu, iiu);
Kfu = K(iif, iiu);
Kuf = K(iiu, iif);
Kff = K(iif, iif);

% rotation tensor corresponding to given angle theta
Q = cos(theta)*e1*e1 - sin(theta)*e1*e2 + sin(theta)*e2*e1 + cos(theta)*e2*e2;

% prescribed displacements of the boundary nodes
% according to the given rotation tensor Q
uu  = dot( (Q-I),x(iiu));
ff  = zeros(1, ee, length(iif), 1);

% solve the system for unknowns
                                        uf = Kff(ff-dot(Kfu,uu));
u = zeros(1, ee, n, 1);
u(iiu) = uu;
u(iif) = uf;

```
                                    fu = dot(Kuu,uu)+dot(Kuf,uf);
```

f = zeros(1, ee, n, 1);
f(iiu) = fu;
f(iif) = ff;

figure(1)
clf
% plot the displacement solution
quiver(x, u, 0);
axis equal
hold on
%femplot(x, conn, 'Color', 'k')
femplot(x+u, conn, 'Color', 'r');
hold off